# $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(0) = 0 = f(1)$ and $|f''|\leq M$. Show $|f'(1/2)| \leq \frac{M}{4}$.

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I attempted a solution using this version of Taylor's Theorem,
\begin{align*}
|f(d) - P_n(d)| &= \left| \frac{f^{n+1}(t)}{(n+1)!} \right| |d-c|^{n+1} \\
|f(d) - f(c) - f'(c)(d-c)| &= \left| \frac{f''(t)}{2} \right| |d-c|^2
\end{align*}
Letting $d=1$ and $c=1/2$ and using the triangle inequality, I get
$$ \frac{|f''(t)|}{4} - \frac{|f(d)-f(c)|}{|d-c|} \geq -|f'(c)| $$

The negative sign on the RHS is throwing me off because otherwise I could easily achieve the desired result. Am I attempting using the wrong theorem or are there any glaring mistakes in my process?